# In jQuery my :contains selector is ignored

Tags: jquery, contains

I'm trying to add a class to an element provided the word 'Yes' appears somewhere in its descendants. So far I've written the below code which applies the class regardless of whether the word appears or not. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".views-row-1 .field-item:contains('Yes')")) {
             $(".views-row-1 .field-name-field-exp").addClass("solexpandable");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
$(".views-row-1 .field-item:contains('Yes')")
```

is always true in a boolean context regardless of what (if anything) it matched. If you want to see if your selector matched anything, check the `length`:

```
if ($(".views-row-1 .field-item:contains('Yes')").length) {
    $(".views-row-1 .field-name-field-exp").addClass("solexpandable");
}
```